# Detect ajax requests by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

is there anyway that i can test against xhr request by using nodejs. Example like webdriver where i can fetch an url and execute javascripts or wait for ajax request to come after page loading?

Comment: You can look for xhr initiator.

Comment: ii mean is there an automatic way?